# Why Is Xcode's Documentation Window Not Working?

Tags: xcode9

When I option click an iOS symbol in Xcode's editor I get a popup summary. Near the bottom there is a link (such as "Class Reference") which should take me to the Documentation for that item. When I click it I am indeed taken to the Documentation Window but the contents of the window do not change - i.e. it continues to display whatever was being displayed before I clicked. In the past these documentation links worked properly. I am not certain if the errant behavior began when I upgraded to Xcode 9. Any help?